# How can I display just a portion of an image in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

Let's say I want a way to display just the the center 50x50px of an image that's 250x250px in HTML. How can I do that. Also, is there a way to do this for css:url() references?

I'm aware of *clip* in CSS, but that seems to only work when used with absolute positioning.

Comment: A List Apart should be in anyones list of sites to visit with HTML/CSS/JS problems: [Here's one way of doing sprites](http://alistapart.com/articles/sprites), [and here's another using JS](http://alistapart.com/articles/sprites2).

Comment: Use a sprite - see here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 130, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the image you want to display as a background in a container (td, div, span etc) and then adjust background-position to get the sprite you want.

Comment: Just to clarify, you’d set the width and height of the container td, div, span or whatever to 50px to make this work.

Comment: @Espo, This seems to be a fairly standard approach, however what if you have a sprite image which contains several individual images of size 32x32, and you want to display 1 of these on a div, span etc that is bigger than 32x32...setting the background-position no longer works.

Comment: @series0ne You could probably combine with [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Answer (score 187):

As mentioned in the question, there is the [`clip`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#clipping) css property, although it *does* require that the element being clipped is `position: absolute;` (which is a shame):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
#clip {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  /* clip: shape(top, right, bottom, left); NB 'rect' is the only available option */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife/3" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="clip" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife/3" />
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ygds2eeu/), for experimentation.

To supplement the original answer – somewhat belatedly – I'm editing to show the use of `clip-path`, which has replaced the now-deprecated `clip` property.

The `clip-path` property allows a range of options (more-so than the original `clip`), of:

- `inset` — rectangular/cuboid shapes, defined with four values as 'distance-from' `(top right bottom left)`.
- `circle` — `circle(diameter at x-coordinate y-coordinate)`.
- `ellipse` — `ellipse(x-axis-length y-axis-length at x-coordinate y-coordinate)`.
- `polygon` — defined by a series of `x`/`y` coordinates in relation to the element's origin of the top-left corner. As the path is closed automatically the realistic minimum number of points for a polygon should be three, any fewer (two) is a line or (one) is a point: `polygon(x-coordinate1 y-coordinate1, x-coordinate2 y-coordinate2, x-coordinate3 y-coordinate3, [etc...])`.
- `url` — this can be either a local URL (using a CSS id-selector) or the URL of an external file (using a file-path) to identify an SVG, though I've not experimented with either (as yet), so I can offer no insight as to their benefit or caveat.

```css
div.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
#rectangular {
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(30px 10px 30px 10px);
  clip-path: inset(30px 10px 30px 10px);
}
#circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(75px at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(75px at 50% 50%)
}
#ellipse {
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(75px 50px at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: ellipse(75px 50px at 50% 50%);
}
#polygon {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 38%, 81% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 38%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 38%, 81% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 38%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="control" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/1" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="rectangular" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/1" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="circle" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/1" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="ellipse" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/1" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="polygon" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/1" />
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/36tg0one/), for experimentation.

References:

- <strike>[`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)</strike> — note: **deprecated**.
- [`clip-path` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [`clip-path` (W3C)](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path).

Comment: amazing find, thanks a lot :) Just FYI, it is not as limited as one would think. If you have a image container div (id="img_container") around img tag, just make img_container position relative, and make img absolute, you can clip the image that way

Comment: "position: absolute; (which is shame)"

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: `clip` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip). Newer [`clip-path`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/) doesn't require positioning

Comment: Good news, the "clip: rect" works in IE8, I have just checked.

Comment: while clip is deprecated many modern browsers do not yet support clip-path. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: `clip` is deprecated and is not recommended to use by MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Comment: @Ada: agreed, I quote from my answer: "*To supplement the original answer – somewhat belatedly – I'm editing to show the use of `clip-path`, which has replaced the now-deprecated `clip` property.*"

Comment: Note that the outside area is only hidden, not cropped, so it's not equivalent to a smaller image.

Answer (score 45):

Another alternative is the following, although not the cleanest as it assumes the image to be the only element in a container, such as in this case:

```
<header class="siteHeader">
  <img src="img" class="siteLogo" />
</header>
```

You can then use the container as a mask with the desired size, and surround the image with a negative margin to move it into the right position:

```css
.siteHeader{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.siteHeader .siteLogo{
    margin: -100px;
}
```

Demo can be seen in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3P44/).

Only seems to work in IE>9, and probably all significant versions of all other browsers.

Comment: Although it is a bitc hacky, it has the plus side that this works in all browsers (clip is deprecated and clip-path does not work in IE) and that it works when You try to print the webpage (background images are skipped by default)

Comment: This is the only truely accross browsers method. All other ways have issues. "Clip" has been depreciated and background-position is not read accurately in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the background-position to move background images in different positions of the `div`:

```css
div { 
  background-image: url('image url');
  background-position: 0 -250px; 
}
```

Comment: Type: `backgroud-image` -> `background-image`.
I was wondering why is my browser not aware of such CSS property and finally I realised it was due to the type.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: no-repeat -100px -100px/500% url("https://qce.quantum.ieee.org/2022/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2022/02/QCE22-250x250-website@1x.jpg")
    };
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem just recently trying to work on one of my own projects for Codecademy. I found out that if you have an image and want to display only a portion of the picture you can position it by doing

```
'background-position: 95% 5%;'
```

Play around with the percentage to see what suits you best. But I believe that this works if you have already displayed your image as a background image.