# getting part of an image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

Is it possible to show any part of image in `img` tag (with pixels) via JavaScript?

I would have a prepared big image (e.g. 32x320 pixels) and defined starting position (X,Y , e.g. 0,32) and width/height (e.g. 32,32), and would want the script to show second (32x32 pixel) part of main image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display just a portion of an image in HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css)

Comment: While referenced question is about html/css, this was for JavaScript.

Comment: are you aware that, since your question was implicitly about JavaScript DOM, and the DOM itself is just a programming backend for HTML/CSS, your question *was* about HTML/CSS itself? The accepted answer here point you to CSS for that very reason. You *can't* do JS DOM *without* taking account of HTML/CSS - even HTML5 canvas element mentioned in the other answer is just that - an HTML5 document element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use CSS properties for this and change them via JS. Set the image as a background for an element with your desired size and adjust its position with background-position so that the correct part of it is visible. Some people call it [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/).

Comment: +1 You don't even have to use a DIV. I use a transparent PNG and set its background-image, which works just as well for this purpose but gives me the option to use the artifact inline if I want to without having to deal with floats, etc.

Comment: Yes, naturally this works with any element. Using an img element sounds somewhat dirty to me though, I'd probably use display: inline-block; if I wanted the element to flow with the text.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of giving you multiple options, you could always use an HTML5 canvas and redraw the image as necessary. You can find a nice tutorial about how to do this here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images
The CSS sprite method would be preferable nonetheless as IE doesn't support canvas yet.

Comment: you can even save the image you drew as a data url http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/