# How Can We Extract Data From the Image displaying on the Web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So when an image is displayed on the web page. How can we select a specific part of the image like region of interest and be able to resize the region of interest and send those ROI's to the backend Using ajax. I am mostly using jquery and ajax for the script part.

I have no Idea of how to do it

Comment: check out this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css

and this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574742/getting-part-of-an-image-with-javascript