# Clip image to a view top center

Tags: android, android-imageview, bitmapimage, clip

So i have this vertical long `Bitmap` :

[image]

On my app i want to display just the top square of the image so it wont eat too much space (vertically). and i want it to look like this :

[image]

get the top most square view of the image and make it look like this :

[image]

without cropping the actual bitmap. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know how but this answer about CSS can help you about concept. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css

Comment: @hakiko i can do this on CSS but its totally different on android. Cant find any source, or sample. And i dont know where to start.