# Crop or Zoom an Image using css

Tags: css, image, zooming, crop

I have a portfolio with small thumbnails that each open in a lightbox.  I'm trying to display the thumbnails as enlarged images. Note, I'm calling the same image for both large version and thumbnail so i need to figure out a way to use css and/or javascript to size thumbnail so they are all the same size, but zoomed in very close.

Here's a sample of the full size image when blown up in a lightbox: http://grab.by/Ax74
Here's the current thumbnail: http://grab.by/Ax7a
Here's what I want the thumbnail to look like (or zoomed in somewhat similar to this): http://grab.by/Ax7k

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css `background-image` in combination with css `background-size`
Check this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27ej45vb/)

e.g.

#### CSS

```css
#div1 {
    background-image: url("url/path");
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

#### EDIT:

Well its pretty hard not using CSS Backgrounds...
for more information check [this](http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_imagetech1.html) and also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css)

nevertheless here is another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ejgae5p/4/). I hope it suits your needs...

```css
.thumbnail {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
    background-position: center; //shows only center of full width image
}



.full {
    width: 609px;
    height: 447px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: initial;
}
```

and also a lil bit javascript

```js
function fullImage() {
    $("#thumbnail").toggleClass("full");
}
```

Comment: I see that definitely works to crop, but I'm looking to zoom on image and preferably not use as a background image either.  Let me know if you have any other ideas.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: What do you mean whit zooming? Do you mean clicking on it so it displays larger?

Comment: No, just want to display a larger selection area so it looks zoomed in.  Check out those screenshots I provided.

Comment: Check my question. I added another fiddle.