# Resposive div with image inside and text

Tags: html, css

I have 3 column in a wrapper div and each div has two div's one with image and one with text.

I want to make it responsive so that image % text share 50% of area and at certain point text is visible & image is hidden or vice versa.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meWYeQ?editors=110

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row inner-wrapper">
            <div class="row footer-quick-links">
                <!--
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 bk-blue no-padding">
                            One
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 bk-dark-blue no-padding">
                            Two
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 bk-magenta no-padding">
                            Three
                        </div>
                -->
                <div class="footer-ql-box bk-dark-blue"><div class="f-img-box"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=163&h=100"></div><div class="f-label-box"><span>OUR MISSION</span></div></div>
                <div class="footer-ql-box bk-blue"><div class="f-img-box"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=163&h=100"></div><div class="f-label-box"><span>VISION</span></div></div>
                <div class="footer-ql-box bk-magenta"><div class="f-img-box"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=163&h=100"></div><div class="f-label-box"><span>CONTACT</span></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: as per the link you are using bootstrap plz make use of the default class there will no need to take care for the responsive class

Answer (score 1):

Add a `100%` to the width to the image inside image box and drop the `absolute` positioning of the image box itself (so the image properly scales it's half).

```
.footer-ql-box img{width:100%; height: 100px;}
.f-img-box{float:left;width:49%;}
```

Note forcing the height to `100px` allows it so the height of the image does not scale down when the window shrinks.

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPpvGg?editors=110)

Comment: Is there a way we can trim image on side to that it doent look disoriented

Comment: You could replace the image with a `<div>` containing a background image, [see this answer for how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css). But it can't be done with just using `<img>`, as that tag is meant to show the entire image.