# Displaying a portion of a image in a div element

Tags: html, css, image

When i have a div that is for example 300*300px and a image that is 1280*560px.
Can i show a specific part of the image in my div while it stays responsive while only using html/css?

the div is always taking up 33% of the page width

my code looks like this:

html

```
<div class="crop">
    <img src="path/to/img">
</div>
```

css

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 300px;
```

Comment: Here is the link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css.
Your issue is similar to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, quite easy, in fact:

```
.image {
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}

.image img {
position: relative;
left: -100px;
top: -100px;
}

<div class="image">
    <img src="http://img05.deviantart.net/c135/i/2011/134/7/0/bridge_by_kzonedd-d3gcetc.jpg" alt="photo of old wooden bridge" />
</div>
```

Of course, the minus 100px just to show you how to position. Play around with the values and all will become clear.

HTH. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Also, px values just to keep it simnple, you can scale both the image and the div any way you like.

Answer (score 3):

Using a background-image might help you in this situation, you can adjust the position of it using `background-position`:

```css
.crop{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/06/13/58/arlberg-pass-833326_960_720.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
</div>
```

Comment: your answer does not explain how to show a portion of the image, it explains how to show a whole image which is not what i am having troubles with.

Comment: @Pizzalord, so when people are trying to help you, you just downvote them, instead of explain better your problem? Check my updated answer.

Comment: i was not the one that downvoted you, i state that you answer before the edit(s) did not solve or partially solve my problem

Comment: @Pizzalord, ok. I was just trying to help. I hope you found the answer to your question.

Comment: nice answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that with flex

this is the code, explaination below

```css
div{
width:300px;
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
div img{
flex:0;
width:auto;
min-height:100%;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src ="http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/safety/notification/products/Mass%20Notification%20Systems/Spotlight/MNS_WideArea_Spotlight3.jpg">
</div>
```

on justify-content you can put flex-start, flex-end, and center to fit which part you want to input horizontally

on align-items you can put the same thing as justify content to adjust vertically.

this image is landscape so i set min-height 100% and width auto, you can do the other side when you got a portrait image. if the image is square, width 100% will do just fine