# How to combine 3 images in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `<img>`.

```
<img id="img1" src="" alt="">
<img id="img2" src="" alt="">
<img id="img3" src="" alt="">
```

I want to show all 3 three of them simultaneously in one `<div>` but each image takes 1/3 of the `<div>` width (also the images should be cropped). And whenever I hover a `image` the column should expand a little and reveal more of the image.

I thought of putting them together in a `<canvas>`and use WebGL but then I think I dont have the possibility to implement hover events. Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe using flex.

Comment: will try it out!

Comment: Normal CSS should be able to show the [portion of the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css/23220895#23220895) you want, I would use JQuery for the hover animation.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xh8qwxzw/) is an example in Bootstrap 3, without flex.

Comment: Normal CSS should even be able to handle the hovering events and expand the correct image (with clip-path probably). Also, don't use jquery, no need to pull in dependencies unnecessarily.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. I will update the question. But I accepted the answer already since downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this if you wanted something in pure CSS. It's a very rudimentary example but should get you started. It uses CSS `clip-path` on the image elements and `transition` to modify the clipping on hover.

```css
#img-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#img-wrap img {
  clip-path: inset(0 66% 0 0);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease .2s;
}

#img-wrap img:nth-of-type(2) { left: 33%; }
#img-wrap img:nth-of-type(3) { left: 66%; }

#img-wrap img:hover {
  clip-path: inset(0 50% 0 0);
  z-index: 10;
}

#img-wrap img:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/39b54a/ffffff/">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/f78200/ffffff/">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/e6001f/ffffff/">
</div>
```

Comment: while this is correct and I accepted it , the number of images is not fixed at three. That is why I considered this a problem(also the images are cropped to a polygon). If the number would be fixed to three then this is the correct solution!