# Hide the left half of an image and show the left half on image hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I simply need two photos with half of each photo (left half visible from left image. right half visible from right image) both images are facing each other.
When hover on left image it shows it's right half and disappears right side image.
And When hover on right image it shows it's left half and left image disappears.

I tried using `overflow:hidden` and `direction:rtl` to hide the left side of right image. Default hides right side.
So when I hover on left image it works perfect and shows hidden part from right side.
But when I hover on left image I can't get the hidden part from left side.

```css
.imagea {
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
}

.imageb {
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  transition: 2s;
}

.imagea:hover {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.imagea:hover~.imageb {
  max-width: 0px;
}

.imageb:hover {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.imageb:hover .imagea {
  max-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagea">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
</div>
<div class="imageb">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try the `clip` as explained on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure CSS solution could be achieved via [CSS specificty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (ie  `+`).

You could enclose the two `img` elements in an `.images` container using [flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to simplify horizontal placement of each image (ie on the "row axis"). By default, style each image so that the:

- occupy 50% of the `.images` container width
- occupy 100% of the containers height
- use `object-position` to align the natural image to the respective side of that image elements boundary

Using the `:hover` pseudo class, the width of image elements are updated so that:

- hovering the `.images` container causes the `.right` image to occupy the full width of the container and the `.left` image to occoupy no space (first case)
- or, hovering the `.left` image (which has greater specifiy than the prior hover case) causes the `.left` image to occupy the full width of the container and the `.right` image to ocupy no space (second case)

In code this can be implemented as:

```css
.images {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

/* Default state of image element */
.images img {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;      
  transition:width ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

/* Default placement of image relative to box boundary */
.left {
  object-position:left;
}
.right {
  object-position:right;
}

/* Hover behavior for first case */
.images:hover .left {
  width:0;
}
.images:hover .right {
  width:100%;
}

/* Hover behavior for second case */
.images .left:hover {
  width:100%;
}
.images .left:hover + .right {
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img class="left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250/FFFF00" />
  <img class="right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250/FF00FF" />
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What Can I do if I want to diagonally cut the two images and do the same thing instead of a straight vertical line?

Comment: @DinukaJayalath unfortunatly this method only supports vertical or horizontal cut lines

Comment: Is there another way that I can use the same functionality with diagonal cut lines?

Comment: @DinukaJayalath there's a posibility that you might be able to achieve this on a diagonal axis with `clip-paths`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/