# HTML / CSS: Keep images in the div box even screen is stretched is and out. And how to target specific area of an image into div?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 issue I am trying to solve.

So I have 5 `<div>` tags inside a parent that has a `display: grid;`

```html
<section class="section2">
  <div class="box6"><img src="img/men-limited.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="box7"><img src="img/women-limited.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="box8"></div>
  <div class="box9"></div>
  <div class="box10"></div>
</section>
```

All my `<div>` tags are lined up next to each other, each `<div>` tag taking 20% of `<body>` width, height: 300px.

In each `<div>` tag, I added 5 different images.

In the CSS file for the images, I have written this code:

```css
.section2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 20%);
}

.box6 {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  height: 350px;
}

.box6>img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.box7 {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  height: 350px;
}

.box7>img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

So this fills the image in current size of the box.

But, this is the problem I am sitting with:
When I stretch the size of the screen, the `<div>` boxes stays at the same height and becomes slimmer, which is great, but the images doesn't follow along, like it doesn't fill the whole height of the `<div>` box anymore. Here is a picture:

[image: images when screen width is smaller]

So the colors are the 5 `<div>` tags.

So, how do I make so that images keeps the `<div>` box filled when I stretch screen in and out?

I will add `@media` later so I get the `<div>` boxes wrapped.

The second question is:

The image is pretty large, and I want to target specific area of the image, lets say I wanna show the left side of the image instead of the center. How do I target a specific area of a large image I wanna show. Image is example 1000 x 1000 but the `<div>` box is 300 x 300, and I wanna target left side instead of center, or I wanna type in the exact pixel area I wanna show. How does that work?

Comment: Please provide html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height: 100% on the images.

```css
.section2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 20%);
}

.box6 {
  background-color: lightsalmon;

  height: 350px;
}

.box6 > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%; //Added Code
}

.box7 {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  height: 350px;
}

.box7 > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%; //Added Code
}
```

```html
<section class="section2">
        <div class="box6"><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="box7"><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="box8"></div>
        <div class="box9"></div>
        <div class="box10"></div>
      </section>
```

As for the second part, I would suggest using background images instead of images and then adjust the background-position to the window you want to show.

Comment: Oh so adding height was the only thing missing haha, Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm suggesting to use background-images combined with background positions, 
This can help as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725/how-can-i-display-just-a-portion-of-an-image-in-html-css.

Comment: The second one is that most of the pictures is going to have "a ref" tag, like most pictures are gonna be clickable. so that was why I was wondering if theres way to control what part of the image I can show in the div box

Comment: you just need to replace your `div` by `a` tags